# Wordpress search results based on user role restrictions

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I'm creating a knowledge base for a company that has multiple b2b brands. For each individual brand a client has to sign an agreement with the company. Clients will be able to login into the knowledge base and see content for the brands they're signed up for.

I'm building this knowledge base in WordPress with Elementor. To restrict content I'm using the 'Content Control' plugin by Code Atlantic. I'm also using the 'User Role Editor' plugin to create user roles per brand.

I've created a custom post type that allows employees of the company to write knowledge base articles. These custom post types are based on categories.

Now everything works fine when someone lands on the homepage. Whenever they click on a certrain brand they're not signed up for the content is inaccesable.

The problem I have is with the search result page. I've created a search rusult page with Elementor. There is a loop widget on there that displays relevent knowledge base articles based on the search query. I however don't want brand articles to show up on this result page if the logged in user is not signed up with a specific brand. If customer A has signed up for brand A they should only see articles from brand A and not from brand B

In the functions PHP.file I've inserted this code:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'custom_search_query');

function custom_search_query($query) {
    if (is_search() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $roles = (array)$user->roles;
        $allowed_roles = array('cenzaa_klanten', 'mayee_klanten');
        $search_categories = array();

        // Define the allowed categories for each role
        if (in_array('cenzaa_klanten', $roles)) {
            $search_categories = array(
                'cenzaa-behandelformulieren',
                'cenzaa-marketing-en-promotiemateriaal',
                'cenzaa-prijslijsten',
                'cenzaa-producthandleidingen',
                'cenzaa-trainingen'
            );
        } elseif (in_array('mayee_klanten', $roles)) {
            $search_categories = array(
                'mayee-behandelformulieren',
                'mayee-prijslijsten',
                'mayee-trainingen'
            );
        }

        // Set the post type and category parameters for the query
        $query->set('post_type', 'artikel');
        $query->set('rubriek_name', implode(',', $search_categories)); // Allow only selected categories
    }

    return $query;
}
```

**Some more info:**
'cenzaa_klanten' and 'mayee_klanten' are the user roles I've made. Cenzaa is one of the brands and Mayee is one of the brands. The 'Content Control' plugin by Code Atlantic is used to set rules for restricted content.

The different catagories start with 'cenza-..' and with 'mayee-..'

With ACF i've changed 'category' to 'rubriek' (Dutch translation of category looks better in url)

Answer (score 0):

For this line of code:

```
$query->set('rubriek_name', implode(',', $search_categories)); // Allow only selected categories
```

If `rubriek_name` is the same as the WP_Query parameter `category_name`, then the code is using a comma separated list to find posts that have **any** of the categories listed in `$search_categories`. The [WordPress WP_Query Docs for category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters) show that `category_name` should be used to find one and **only one** category name (slug). The parameter value should be a string representing a single category (not a comma separated list).

To search for **any** category in a list, an array of category IDs should be used with the WP_Query parameter `category__in`.

Since we already have an array of category names (slugs) as `$search_categories`, we can use something like this to find the array of category IDs:

```
$category_ids = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'category',
        'fields'     => 'ids',              // Return an array of term IDs.
        'hide_empty' => true,               // Default. Hide categories not assigned to any posts.
        'slug'       => $search_categories,
        'number'     => 0                   // Default. Do not limit the number of IDs returned.
    )
);
```

To update the `$query`, we could use something like this:

```
$query->set('rubriek__in', $category_ids);
```

This assumes `rubriek__in` is the same as the WP_Query parameter `category__in`.